# Unable to create semaphore with sem_open

Tags: c, ipc, semaphore

I'm trying to create a semaphore, but my code doesn't pass the first check and prints: "sem_open/producer: No such file or directory".

Note that SEM_CONSUMER_FNAME and SEM_PRODUCER_FNAME were defined in shared_memory.h.

Can someone lend me a hand, please?

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h> 
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <signal.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include "map.h"
#include <errno.h>
#include "shared_memory.h"
#include <semaphore.h>
#include <sys/ipc.h>
#include <sys/shm.h>
#include <fcntl.h> 
#include <sys/stat.h> 


int main(){     
        
    //Remove semaphores with same name;
    sem_unlink(SEM_CONSUMER_FNAME);
    sem_unlink(SEM_PRODUCER_FNAME);  
    
    //Setup some semaphores
    sem_t *sem_prod = sem_open(SEM_PRODUCER_FNAME, IPC_CREAT, 0660, 0);
    if (sem_prod == SEM_FAILED){
        perror("sem_open/producer");
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }   
    
    sem_t *sem_cons = sem_open(SEM_CONSUMER_FNAME, IPC_CREAT, 0660, 1);
    if (sem_cons == SEM_FAILED) {
        perror("sem_open/consumer");
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }
```

Comment: O_CREAT not IPC_CREAT

Comment: That fixed the problem!

Comment: Thank you! I had seen someone creating it with IPC_CREAT, I don't know how they did it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to [this man page](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/sem_open.3.html),

> The `oflag` argument specifies flags that control the operation of
> the call.  (Definitions of the flags values can be obtained by
> including `<fcntl.h>`.)  If `O_CREAT` is specified in `oflag`, then the
> semaphore is created if it does not already exist.

That is `O_CREAT`, not `IPC_CREAT`.